# How to get path paramters from URL string in java

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I want to create function which will take URL string as a parameter and return 
`MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>`  as a output. I have format of url with me through which I can construct UriTemplate  class.

So basically I want to create functionality similar to `requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters()`

So my function will be

```
public MultivaluedHashMap<String, String> getPathParamtersFromUrl(string url)
{
}
```

I am not sure how to get this. 
Note : I don't want to extract query parameters. I want to extract path parameters.

Comment: Which part of writing the code do you have problem with? Show us what you have and explain which part troubles you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure out solution after closely looking at the UriTemplate class.

```
 private MultivaluedMap<String, String> getPathParameters(String uri, String strUrlTemplate) {

        UriTemplate template = new UriTemplate(strUrlTemplate);
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        Boolean value = template.match(uri, parameters);
        return new MultivaluedHashMap(parameters);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the path parameter list other than the http scheme and the domain name.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428388/how-to-get-path-paramters-from-url-string-in-java";
    System.out.println("The path parameters of url:" + url);
    List<String> p = getPathParametersFromUrl(url);
    p.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
}

private static List<String> getPathParametersFromUrl(String url) {
    String[] path = url.split("\\?");
    String[] pathparams = path[0].split("\\//");
    String[] param = pathparams[1].split("\\/");
    List<String> p = Arrays.asList(param);
    return p.stream().filter(x -> !x.contains(".")).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```